# Server need to connect to set update android studio

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, sdk, installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in a private network, it's hard to connect to other sites.

I need to install Android Studio which can be download offline. But when installing Android Studio, there are some components which need to download such as SDK.

So what server the Android Studio will use to download SDK and other needed components? I'll request to access that server.

Comment: Fixed spelling and added paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

[Linux SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#tos-header)

You can download it from the official site and install it.

Or you can do one thing that setup the android environment in different linux system which is on open network and then copy whole SDK folder into the private network system and just give path in the Android studio.